# payment processing with django

Tags: django, payment-gateway

I am trying to build code that allows people to pay for the services that they get from my website. I have built the form using the forms.Form model available in django. I have also used the following pattern to build my view.

```
if request.method == 'POST'
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        conn = urllib2.Request(payment_gateway_url,urllib.urlencode(my_dat_in_dict))
        f= urrlib2.urlopen(conn)
        all_results=f.read()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

return render(request, 'contact.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

The problem i am facing is that my forms get submitted OK and the payment gateway responds back to me with a whole bunch of html that helps the user to choose the credit card details etc in the response to this form POST(details that i am not collecting on my website). I can see this in the all_results (f.read()).

My question is that how do i show the user this page, since i get this as a result of my form POST. Should i save this response in a html file and HTTPResponseredirect to that page. I am assuming that HTTPResponseRedirect is more for a complete transaction and not the intermediate responses.

So, basically how do i handle the situation where the user will get sent to the payment gateway site and then after completing the proceedings come back to my site?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would say, if you live in the US, check out Stripe (or something similar). The way you are describing your payment process seems a bit overly complicated.

With that said, if (and I doubt this is the case), the HTML returned from the most is in the correct format for display on your website, you can just stick it in to an HttpResponse (must be a sprint)

return HttpResponse(html)

Otherwise, use something like BeautifulSoup, Scrape.py, or something similar to format it IN RAM, and then use HttpResponse. I would not write it to the file system for modification.

Comment: i am in india. I tried that and it does render the page. But i think the problem i am facing is that what is the general way to handle the code in the above mentioned pattern, when the situation is the following  - The right form fields are posted through urrlib2.urlopen(). The Payment Gateway vendor redirects you to his website where you enter CC information. After submitting the details, the vendor returns the final status of the transaction which is then available to store in one's own database.